# What are these characters?

Tags: translation, character-meanings

This is perhaps an odd request, but can someone please help me to identify the Korean characters in this image? This is my brother's Tae Kwon Do black belt, mine managed to get accidentally thrown out when I recently moved house and I need to have a new one embroidered. However, they need a clean version of the characters for their machine to be able to embroider them.

I can't go back to the person who originally did it as I was awarded my 1st Dan in 1991 and they are unfortunately long gone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Korean belt characters]

Comment: 팜레이 도장 = 팜레이 (Tae Kwon Do) school. Here 팜레이=Pamray may be a teacher's name.

Comment: @HKLee That would be correct, my school's name was Parmley Dojang, so a close approximation for a Western name.

Comment: @JaneS I've loved your answers at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and they've been very helpful. Happy to see you here. Welcome to KorLang stackexchange

Comment: @user17915 Thank you! It was the first place I looked for assistance and the community here was immediately helpful and resolved my issue quickly. I hope that this stack will continue to prosper and grow! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“팜레이 도장” written a fancy way. “Parmley(’s) [dojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo).”